# Converting VS 2013 SPA template from knockout to kendo

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, requirejs, single-page-application

I'm putting an eye on kendo ui framework. My initial try facing several problems that I'm not sure how to fix them. Your help will guide me to better understand kendo:

```
define(['kendo', 'security-dataservice', 'security-model', 'security-helper', 'security-authservice', 'router', 'ajaxPrefilters'],
function (kendo, dataservice, model, helper, authservice, router) {
    var userInfo = new kendo.data.ObservableObject({
        userName: "",
        password: "",
        rememberMe: false,
        loggingIn: false,
        errors: [],

        loadingExternalLogin: false,
        externalLoginProviders: [],
        hasExternalLogin: function () {
            return this.get("externalLoginProviders").length > 0;
        },
        login: function () {
            //var self = this;
            //if (typeof (this.get("userInfo.errors")) !== 'undefined')
                this.get("userInfo.errors").splice(0, this.get("userInfo.errors").length);

            this.set("userInfo.loggingIn", true); // THIS LINE IS WORKING PROPERLY WHILE INSIDE .done AND .failJSON NOT WORKING

            var name = this.get("userInfo.userName");
            var pass = this.get("userInfo.password");

            dataservice.login({
                grant_type: "password",
                UserName: name,
                Password: pass // Up to here the code is working correctly**
            }).done(function (data) {
                //this.set("userInfo.loggingIn", false); // << This line does not working with "uncaught TypeError"
                this.loggingIn = false; // Is this line correct?

                if (data.userName && data.access_token) {
                    authservice.logUserIn(data.userName, data.access_token, this.rememberMe);
                } else {
                    //this.get("errors").push("An unknown error occurred.");
                    userInfo.errors.push("An unknown error occurred.");
                }
            }).failJSON(function (data) {
                this.loggingIn = false;

                if (data && data.error_description) {
                    userInfo.errors.push(data.error_description);
                } else {
                    userInfo.errors.push("An unknown error occurred.");
                }
                //if (data && data.error_description) {
                //    this.get("errors").push(data.error_description);
                //} else {
                //    this.get("errors").push("An unknown error occurred.");
                //}
            });
        }
    });

    return {
        userInfo: userInfo
    }
});
```

**My questions are:**

1- Internet explorer does not go throw the .done and .failJSON while the code is working properly in Chrome and Firefox.

2- Why the line this.set("userInfo.userName") is not recognized and giving uncaught typeerror the 'set' is not defined.

3- Does this.loggingIn = false; is correctly set the property loggingIn? or should I do something else.

4- Are there any template that covers web API authentication using kendo MVVM + requires

FYI: this code is a step forward to translate Visual Studio Web API SPA template from knockout to kendo binding.

Comment: These are several unrelated issues; I suggest creating a separate question for each issue.

Comment: I would suggest continuing to use Knockout.js, as it has a lot of great things, but there is a thing called Knockout-Kendo.js http://rniemeyer.github.io/knockout-kendo/  This works by combining knockout and kendo. If you are going mobile though, knockout will not work in kendo mobile framework unfortunately

Comment: @LarsHöppner: I'm sorry for gathering several questions but I thing they are all related to Kendo+JQuery,Ajax. I wonder how can I separate them in three questions.

Comment: @Ohjay44: Thank you for your reference, but do I need to factory  kendo to knockout to do this task. I think that Kendo is enough. The above code is binding to my view and login services are working without any issues. Do you thing my questions are more related to JavaScript?

Comment: the three issues I see are 1) kendo's observable and scope; 2) IE behaving differently; (you'll need to clarify what dataservice is/does) 3) authentication and Web API

Comment: @LarsHöppner you catch my interest. Please find out any corrections to my mentioned code about Scope. I may post the same quest to IE behaving differently. I do not have any problem about web API and security scenarios that will be accomplished to my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues with scoping here:

First: it should be

```
this.set("loggingIn", true);
```

since `this` in this context is the observable object, and the property you want to set is `loggingIn`.

Then in the functions you pass to `done()` and `failJSON()`, you'll need to use `userInfo.set()` instead of `this.set()`, since apparently the data service is setting the context for the function:

```
var that = this;
dataservice.login({
    grant_type: "password",
    UserName: name,
    Password: pass // Up to here the code is working correctly**
}).done(function (data) {
    that.set("loggingIn", false); 
    // ...
})
```

Comment: I have tried 

>> this.Set("loggingIn", true);

>> this.set("userInfo.loggingIn", true);

>> userInfo.Set("loggingIn", true);

>> this.parent.set("loggingIn", true);

all with no luck and always giving uncaught typeerror: 'set' is not a function and typeerror. 'userinfo' is not defined

Comment: FYI: I did not change the dataservice from original template. I also isolated the shell from Visual Studio 2013 SPA template. I have only login with its viewmodel and kendo router.

the data service looks like this:
        var login = function (data) {
            return $.ajax(loginUrl, {
                type: "POST",
                data: data
            });
        };

Comment: I have tried >> userInfo.parent.set("loggingIn", false); and still no luck.

Comment: Thank you very much it is working now in Firefox and Chrome. I have tried var self = this; but actually I should use var that = this; You answered 2nd and 3rd question. I wish I could find an answer to the first question :)